# Search bar on top of the mainscreen blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I want to make one search bar on top of the mainscreen and this search bar should include one editfield and one image of search icon.
Please help me...

Thanks, in advance

Comment: actually uptil now i managed to put one editfield and one image of search. i have to put the image after editfield in horizontal field and after that the search icon but i am unable to do so, but i successfully placed the search icon and then after editfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an HorizontalFieldManager to put editfield and image on the same line. Read here http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/HorizontalFieldManager.html and here: http://www.androidadb.com/class/ho/HorizontalFieldManager.html , a simple example showing how adding two buttons in an HorizontalFieldManager. Just substitute buttons with yor needed fields.

Or you can play with GridFieldMgr:

```
        GridFieldManager gridMgr_g = new GridFieldManager(1, 2, 0);
        gridMgr_g.setColumnProperty(0, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, screenWidth-myBitmapRes.width);
        gridMgr_g.setColumnProperty(1, GridFieldManager.FIXED_SIZE, myBitmapRes.width);

        gridMgr_g.add(new EditField());
        gridMgr_g.add(new BitmapField(Bitmap.getBitmapResource(myBitmapRes)));

        add(gridMgr_g);
```

Comment: i had done the same, I had taken two horizontal field managers and put that into one vertical field manager and added it onto the screen but not got exactly what i want to do i m able to add the search bar image and then the editfield but i want to add editfield and then after the image, please help